# Is there a file in the link php

Tags: php

Please tell me how I can check for an error in the fopen function, namely, whether the file is located at this link. The link may or may not work.

```
$url = "https://test.com/file/";

if (fopen($url, "r")) {
    file_put_contents("test.mp3", fopen($url, "r")); 
}
else {
}
```

So for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: Is not very clear what you're asking for, you want to check if the fopen will throw an error? Or you what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Lucarnosky Yes that's right. The link may be broken and I need to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use try catch ?

```
try {
  file_put_contents("test.mp3", fopen($url, "r"));
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo($e->getMessage()); // Whatever handling you want if the fopen fails
}
```

Comment: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in

Comment: Well that means that you are not allowed to do such request, doesn't come from the try catch itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions, or you will wrap it in a `try - catch` block or you can previously check if the file is available via curl

```
$ch = curl_init("https://test.com/file/");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Check the retcode, if is 200 the file is there and you can proceed, otherwise you need to handle it